# Javascript does not work under JSF template

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I'm using JSF templates and Primefaces.

Javascript code does not seem to be working under ui:composition and ui:define tags. The following code is not hitting the loaded() method. This is the content.xhtml file

```
<h:head>
<script language="javascript">
    function loaded() {
        alert("Working!!");
    }
</script>
</h:head>

<ui:composition template="/template/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
<h:body style="width:100%;height:100%;" onload="loaded()">
     <p class="item">Random text</p>
</h:body>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

but when i remove the define and composition tags the loaded function is called. Any idea why this is happening ?

Here is the template file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<h:head>
<title><ui:insert name="title">Template</ui:insert></title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

<div id="header">
    <ui:insert name="header">
        <ui:include src="../menu.xhtml" />
    </ui:insert>
</div>


<div id="content">
    <ui:insert name="content">
        <ui:include src="../content.xhtml" />
    </ui:insert>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <ui:insert name="footer">
        This is a footer
    </ui:insert>
</div>
```

Comment: See the difference in generated HTML in both cases

Comment: Good idea :) ... Just checked and it looks like the loaded() method is not being added to the output html.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Everything *outside* `<ui:composition>` is **ignored** during building the view. Also, redeclaring `<h:body>` once again is unnecessary. To use a script which runs during on page load, better use a `<h:outputScript target="body">`. This will be relocated to end of body and thus be invoked *after* the necessary HTML DOM elements are been built. This is also somewhat faster than an `onload`.

All with all, your *entire* `content.xhtml` must look like this:

```
<ui:composition template="/template/template.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:outputScript target="body">
            alert("Working!!");
        </h:outputScript>

        <p class="item">Random text</p>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)

Comment: Awesome!! That worked. Thanks heaps BalusC ... You are a super hero here on Stackoverflow. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing "content" to the template.  If your template does not include "content", it won't be including in the resulting HTML.

Post the template.xhtml and let's see...

Comment: Steve I've edited the question and added the template.xhtml file