# h:selectManyChexkbox`s <f:ajax event="click" listener doesn't fire and gives an error

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, event-handling, selectmanycheckbox

I want to fire an event change listener when the user selects / deselects something in the h:selectManyCheckbox, if it leaves it alone nothing should happen.

My xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="/juritest/resources/css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/juritest/resources/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/juritest/resources/js/menu.js"></script>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<ui:composition template="../../templates/gridsTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        ...
                <h:panelGroup style="text-align: left">
                    <hr />
                    <h:selectManyCheckbox
                        value="#{gridPopUpBean.oneQuestionUserAnswers}" 
                        layout="pageDirection">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="a"
                            itemLabel="#{gridPopUpBean.currentQuestion.a}" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="b"
                            itemLabel="#{gridPopUpBean.currentQuestion.b}" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="c"
                            itemLabel="#{gridPopUpBean.currentQuestion.c}" />
                        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{gridPopUpBean.changeListener()}"/>
                    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                </h:panelGroup>
   ...
```

I get an error saying "One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view." I have < h:head> not just < head>, I read that this was a possible problem.

And the snippet from the bean:

```
public void changeListener(ValueChangeEvent e) {

    change = true;
}
```

I have tried without < f:ajax like

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox
                        value="#{gridPopUpBean.oneQuestionUserAnswers}" valueChangeListener="#{gridPopUpBean.changeListener()}" onclick="submit()"
                        layout="pageDirection">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="a"
                            itemLabel="#{gridPopUpBean.currentQuestion.a}" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="b"
                            itemLabel="#{gridPopUpBean.currentQuestion.b}" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="c"
                            itemLabel="#{gridPopUpBean.currentQuestion.c}" />
                        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{gridPopUpBean.changeListener()}"/>
                    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

but with no luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view." I have < h:head> not just < head>, I read that this was a possible problem.*

Anything outside `<ui:composition>` is **ignored**. If you need a `<h:head>`, it needs to go in the master template, the `gridsTemplate.xhtml` (or any of its parent templates).

Further, if you aren't using a visual editor for your XHTML files (like Dreamweaver), then I strongly recommend to stop putting any content outside `<ui:composition>`, [otherwise you keep confusing yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991653/javascript-does-not-work-under-jsf-template-again).

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)

---

> ```
> <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{gridPopUpBean.changeListener()}"/>
>
> public void changeListener(ValueChangeEvent e) {
> ```

You're confusing `valueChangeListener` with `<f:ajax listener>`. The `ValueChangeEvent` argument is only applicable to `valueChangeListener` attribute of an `UIInput` component. Get rid of that argument.

```
public void changeListener() {
```

#### See also:

- [When to use valueChangeListener or f:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener/11883021#11883021)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you correctly used `click` (although you could safely omit it altogether), but your question title mentions `change` and that is indeed the wrong event for a checkbox and radio button.

#### See also:

- [What values can I pass to the event attribute of the f:ajax tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag/7889098#7889098)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am sorry for the inconvenience of answering my trivial and sometimes idiotic questions. I really appreciate taking the time to answer.